# VBA MS-Word: Find and Replace "^13" always add another "^13"

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a new document and tried to program a simple find and replace procedure which will find `^13` and replace it with `^p` but everytime I run it, it will simply add another `^13` and don't replace it. What would be the problem? Here is my code:

```
Do While .Find.Execute(FindText:="^13", Forward:=True, MatchWildcards:=False, _
    replacewith:="^p", Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Wrap:=wdFindContinue)
    Exit Do
Loop
```

I even use `^p`, `chr(13)` or `chr$(13)` but the result is still the same.

Comment: Was the dccument you're running this on creaetd in Word or some other software? Sometimes other software use a character combination for carriage returns that Word's converter doesn't handle quite right, linking the Chr(13) with some other character, so that a Replace can't remove the one that was there...

Comment: (a) what are you trying to achieve when replacing ^13 by ^p? and (b) are you saying that *every* ^13 (perhaps every paragraph mark, or perhaps something else in your document)  is replaced by ^13^13 (what does that look like?) - here, I find that Word only inserts an extra pargraph mark at the end of the document - is that what you are seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this algorithm to do this (in all steps used find replace procedure):

1. Change symbol ^ to another that not using in document, example @@@@@@;
2. Change anothersymbol13 to anothersymbolp,  for my example @@@@@@13 to @@@@@@p;
3. change anothersymbol to ^^ (two ^) to replace back symbol ^, for my example @@@@@@ to ^^

Comment if you use your find replace procedure by word interface, use menu, you get error - IS NOT A VALID SPECIAL CHARACTER FOR THE REPLACE WITH-BOX